# Error message at the lines with scanf?

Tags: c, scanf

```
//Get Celcius

double getCelsius()

{
    double c;
    printf("Please enter a temperature in degrees Celcius");
    scanf("%f",double c);
    return c;
}

double getFahrenheit()//FUNCTION DECLARATION
{
    double f;//VARIABLE DECLARATION
    printf("Please enter a temperature in degrees Fahrenheit");
    scanf("%f", double f);
    return f;
}
```

Comment: If you have to ask on Q&A sites what compiler errors mean, your computer science career is going to be very short.

Comment: Minor: spelling [Celsius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celsius), not "degrees Celcius".

Answer (score 3):

`%lf` is needed for scanning a double with `scanf` . Also `scanf("%lf",&c);`  and `scanf("%lf",&f);`

Answer (score 0):

remove `double` from scanf

```
scanf("%lf",&c);
```

Comment: Compiles but probably won't work. See T.J.'s answer.